# How can I dynamically nest vue components?

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to add one component inside other when user clicks a button. but how can we render the component in the virtual dom.
I tried using v-html but its not working.
Whats the best way to solve this issue?

```js
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            elements : {
                hotel : '<hotel-form></hotel-form>'
            },
            

        }
    },
  methods:{
      addHotel(){
          
          console.log('add');
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="container" style="margin-top:300px;">
      <div class="row" id="mainform">
          <div v-for="item in elements">
              <div v-html="item"></div>
          </div>

      </div>
      <button @click="addHotel()">add hotel</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Is this about a list of hotels or a list of elements that can contain other component types as well?

Comment: its not list of hotels but the hotel-form component contains a form to add a new hotel.

Comment: So you have multiple hotel forms in your list? Or why don't you just toggle visibility of the form when the button is pressed?

Comment: thats a good approach but i have multiple forms for hotels, flights and flight halts and others also. so thats the reason i want to do it dynamically. Is it possible to achieve this behaviour with vue

Comment: Ok I get it. Don't you have any data that has to be passed to your forms?

Comment: What I mean is you could make "elements" an array like ['hotel','flight','hotel'] and then conditionally render the matching components. The add button would simply push another string to the array.

Answer (score 1):

I would bind an array (`hotels`) to a `<hotel-form>` component tag via `v-for`. This way, no `hotel-form` components will be initially rendered, and then you can push an object (with any data to want bound to the `hotel-form` component) to the `hotels` array and the DOM will automatically render a new corresponding `hotel-form` component.

Here's a simple example:

```js
Vue.component('hotel-form', {
  template: '#hotel-form',
  props: { id: Number, name: String },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { hotels: [], count: 0 }
  },
  methods: {
    addHotel() {
      this.hotels.push({ name: 'foo', id: this.count++ })
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div id="mainform">
    <hotel-form v-for="hotel in hotels" :key="hotel.id" v-bind="hotel">
    </hotel-form>
  </div>
  <button @click="addHotel">add hotel</button>
</div>

<template id="hotel-form">
  <div>
    <h4>Hotel Form #{{ id }}</h4>
    <div>{{ name }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```